Is a porch light with integrated outlet safe / to code?
I visited a lighting store in town that sells dozens of front porch lights.  None of them have an integrated GFCI outlet, which would be handy for my situation.  The sales manager said that such an outlet is not to code and so they don't carry any such lights.
But I see them for sale elsewhere, including by major brands. For instance, a Hampton Bay item at Home Depot: "Mission Style Black with Bronze Highlight Outdoor Wall Lantern with Built-In Electrical Outlet (GFCI) Model #30264" has two integrated GFCI outlets and is UL-certified.
I see why GFCI protection is essential given that the plugged-in load could be exposed to water or fail in a dangerous way.  With that in mind, is it to code for a porch light mounted on a wall to have integrated GFCI outlets?  In case it matters, this fixture is about a foot below a porch roof and two feet inside the side edge of such roof, so it will not be exposed to direct rainfall.

Why wouldn't it be safe/to code as long as the outlet is GFCI?  The light by itself would be safe.  The outlet is safe because it has a weather resistant cover.

The light fixture must be located low enough that the GFCI test & reset buttons meet the definition of accessible (I think 78 inches or less without looking it up for this use.) Thus, one hung from the porch ceiling would probably not be to code. Since you have only specified distance below the porch ceiling, and not distance above the floor, unclear if the location meets the definition from information supplied.

Look at NEC 210.8, 210.50(E), and 406.9(A).
If the item includes a weather-resistant-type receptacle (often branded "WR") then it could be up to code for a covered porch.
According to the Home Depot advertisement,

Electrical outlet: Easily accessible integrated GFCI (ground fault circuit interrupter)

This is a feature, not a requirement.  GFCI protection can be provided from other locations.

Outdoor usage: UL listed for wet locations

This meets one of the requirements for the light, but not the receptacle.  NEC 406.9(B) requires a receptacle in a wet location to be "identified as the weather-resistant type".

"Damp" and "wet" locations are defined.  I don't know the exact wording, but it comes down to things directly exposed to the weather, such as on outlet that can have direct rain on it, is a wet location.  And things outdoors, but shielded from direct rain such as under a porch roof, are classified as damp locations.
So it sounds like in your situation you have a damp location, so if the fixture is rated by the manufacturer for a damp location, then you should be good.
